# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '%'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm going through the flask megatutorial by Miguel G. right now and I've hit this problem where when try to boot up the application using template inheritance for the html structure, I come across this error:

**TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '%'**.

My code looks like this, for reference.

```html
<html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content % }
        <h1> Hello, {{user.nickname}}! </h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div><p>{{post.author.nickname}} says: <b>{{post.body}}</b>/<p></div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
</html>
~
```

any advice on what's going wrong with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have a space on the second line `% }`

Comment: FYI I got this issue by having a statement like:

```{% from "test.html" import
  abc,
  def,
%}
```

And I just had to remove the trailing comma.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The space between `%` and `}` on 2nd line causes the problem. Remove it and it'll work.

Comment: Wecome to SO. Please refrain from answering such questions that are only caused by typos, as their fate is to be closed and deleted. Furthermore, the answer had already been given in a previous answer and a comment.

Answer (score 7):

You got typo, change `% }` to `%}`.

```
<html>
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %} {# <- TYPO WAS HERE #}
        <h1> Hello, {{user.nickname}}! </h1>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div><p>{{post.author.nickname}} says: <b>{{post.body}}</b>/<p></div>
        {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
</html>
```